# Why is xenon hexafluoride not stored in glass?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, noble-gases, glass, containers

Why is $\ce{XeF_6}$ not stored in glass containers? Isn't the reason glass is used for most acids is that it is non-reactive?

Comment: Aren't there lots of fluorides you can't store in glass?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\ce{XeF_6}$ can't be stored in glass as it reacts with the silica that makes up the glass

$\ce{2XeF_6 + SiO_2 -> 2XeOF_4 + SiF_4}$

This can proceed further to eventfully make $\ce{XeO_3}$:

$\ce{2XeOF_4 + SiO_2 -> 2XeO_2F_2 + SiF_4}$

$\ce{2XeO_2F_2 + SiO_2 -> 2XeO_3 + SiF_4}$

Dry $\ce{XeO_3}$ is highly explosive ...

That is why both $\ce{XeOF_4}$ and $\ce{XeF_6}$ are stored in nickel containers at room temperature.

These are generally considered as acid-base reactions using the Lux-Flood definition, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Lux.E2.80.93Flood_definition

I don't have them to hand but any decent University level Inorganic Chemistry text book such as Housecroft and Sharpe or Greenwood and Earnshaw should cover this.